# Double slit experiment with different paths - How to make such an experiment?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, double-slit-experiment

In the double-slit experiment, if we could make the electron traveling through slit $A$ to travel longer distances then the electron traveling through slit $B$, what would be the result?

I was trying to ask that question [earlier](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/554469/double-slit-experiment-with-different-paths), but I didn't realize the untrivial problem of setting up such an experiment. The challenge is to build it in a way that the extra distance we are adding for electrons going through slit $A$ will not reveal what desition they made, in other words the electrons should remain in a superposition until they hit the screen.

Please tell me if you believe that such an experiment is possible, and if you do, how would you construct it?

[image]

Comment: Are you able to set up such experiments? Maybe it is easier to work on the following setup. Make the slits on glass. Vaporize metal on them. Keep the left, the middle and the right edges isolated from each other. Now apply positive electrical potential to the left and right edges. Some electrons will not pass through, but end up at the edges. Others will be deflected, and the prediction of this experiment will be the appearance of separate stripes on the left and right edges. As I commented in an earlier of your questions,

Comment: ...  slits are not necessary for fringes at all. It is sufficient to have an edge and a well collimated beam.

Answer (score 0):

For any position on the screen other than the center line, the length of the electrons' paths are different.  The result is alternating constructive and destructive interference, i.e., fringes.   If you can somehow lengthen one leg, then the result would be the same, but the geometry would be different.  The center of the diffraction pattern would not be in the center of the screen. Rather it would be at the location where the path lengths *are* the same.  In other words, you would see the same fringe pattern that you get with the unaltered system, except that the pattern is displaced.

Comment: _For any position on the screen other than the center line, the length of the electrons' paths are different_ Correct me if I got you wrong, you are suggesting to use the original double-slit experiment and drawing conclusions about the electron path based on the result. However in the original experiment the distance between the slits and the board is the same. This is the part of the experiment I would like to modify, and the question is how?

Comment: What I mean is this:  we have a left slit and a right slit.   On the screen, at a point midway between the projection of the slits (i.e., the middle of the screen) the path lengths from the two slits is the same.   Consider a point on the screen to the right of center.  To get to that point electrons from the left slit have a longer distance to travel than do electrons from the right slit.  It is exactly this difference in distance that provides the phase shift that produces interference fringes.