# Quantum Superposition and path length

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin, superposition

Q based on Allan Adams' Online Intro to Superposition MIT lecture.  His simplification is electrons with two properties Color(PC) (White or Black) and Hardness(PH) (Hard of Soft).  If you measure PC and out pops a W electron and you measure PC again it'll alway be W.  But if you measure PC as W and then measure PH and then measure PC again it'll come out 50/50 W/B.  But if you take W electrons and measure PH and recombine BOTH the H/S output paths with mirrors and then measure PC again it'll be back to 100% W due to Superposition.  Q: If you made one path much longer than the other through the use of mirrors is Superposition affected?  If not, then when does the electron exit the "Superposition box" and have its color measured?  The time to travel the short path for H or the long path for S?  Interesting coincidence is just after coming up with this Q I see the newish 3 slit experiment which appears to involve superposition where one path is longer than the other although they don't seem to address that aspect.

Comment: I am finally finding some similar questions asked.  However, in the below the increase in the path length via mirrors is on the wrong side of the slits from what I'm trying to ask.  I need to study several questions the seem to be related to clarify my question.
https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/554469/double-slit-experiment-with-different-paths

Comment: IN wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stern–Gerlach_experiment under the sequential section you can see what Pr. Adams is referencing.  Path length is not important. The important concept is that measuring the spin can disturb the spin. Pr. Adam creates a lot of drama in his classroom video ....wanting to make QM mysterious and magical  and interesting fo this students.  But blindly looking at probabilities only and ignoring or masking the real physics is a little disingenuous.

Comment: @PhysicsDave Assuming you can send one electron at a time through the device when does the final detector detect it if the two paths are vastly different in length?